# Subscribing to behaviour subject, modifying data & setting value again resulting in infinite loop

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject, angular-guards

We have a wizard functionality, wherein we have a lazy loaded module having a parent component & multiple child components.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path : '',
    component :  WizardHomeComponent,
    canActivate: [HomeGuard],
    children : [
      {
        path : 'route1',
        component :  C1Component,
        canActivate: [ChildGuard]
      },
      {
        path : 'route2',
        component :  C2Component,
        canActivate: [ChildGuard]
      },
      {
        path : 'route3',
        component :  C3Component,
        canActivate: [ChildGuard]
      }
      {
        path : 'complete',
        component :  CompleteFlowComponent,
        canActivate: [ChildGuard]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The `HomeGuard` basically refers to service, which if no data is there, makes an API call after that we set the `Behaviour Subject` value in the service & resolve the guard.

```
HomeGuard

return new Observable(observer=> { 
  this.apiService.getAPIResult().subscribe(res=>{
    this.subjectService.setRequestData(res)  // Inside the subject service, setting the value for the behaviour subject
    observer.next(true)
  });
})
```

Here is the code for the subject service

```
Subject Service 

private requestDataSource : BehaviorSubject<IWizard[]> = new BehaviorSubject<IWizard[]>(null);
public _requestData: Observable<IWizard[]> = this.requestDataSource.asObservable();

get requestData() {
  return this._requestData;
}

setRequestData(state) {
  this.requestDataSource.next(state);
}
```

Now, we have child route guard i.e **ChildGuard** . It basically subscribes to the behaviour subject & checks for condition & thereby allow entry to child component.

```
ChildGuard

return this.subjectService.requestData
  .pipe(
    tap(wizard => {
      activeStep = wizard.filter(x=>x.isActive == true);
      /* Some othe logic for conditions */
    })
  )
  .pipe(
    map(wizard => isAllowed)
  )
```

Now, inside our child route components, whenever user traverse, I am updating the `isActive` attribute & that is being used inside the guard for checking.

The issue is when the user hits the browser back button, the values are not set in the behaviour subject & entry to the child component is not allowed.
To try on a solution, Inside the **WizardHomeComponent**, I am subcribing to **requestData** observable & trying to modify & set the subject again but that goes into an infinite loop.

```
WizardHomeComponent
this.subjectService.requestData.subscribe(res=>{
    /* Code to edit the res */
    const modifiedData = this.modificationFunction(res);
    this.subjectService.setRequestData(modifiedData)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like it to fire once, you can try something like this:
It only takes the first value emitted.

```js
WizardHomeComponent
this.subjectService.requestData.pipe(
  first(), // Only take the first value emitted
  map(res => this.modificationFunction(res)) /* Code to edit the res */
).subscribe(modifiedData =>
  this.subjectService.setRequestData(modifiedData)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem in your structure. I think you should have a parameter in your URL and get the data from backend and set the requestData in a service. not in a component.

but with a simple null checking (or whatever checking!) your problem will be solved.

```
this.subjectService.requestData.subscribe(res=>{
    if(!this.checkValidation(res)) {
        /* Code to edit the res */
        const modifiedData = this.modificationFunction(res);
        this.subjectService.setRequestData(modifiedData)
    }
});

checkValidation(res){
//check if res is in modifiedData shape
}
```